# How does a user input a filename?

Tags: python, io

I've written code for an assembler, but I am still new to python.
In my code I have the user input a file that will be converted into an assembly language.  I think I've almost got it working, but I can't figure out where the user enters the file name.
I'm in *(what I think is)* IDLE, and then when I hit F5 it runs in the shell. I'm getting an error, but I'm pretty sure it's because no file name has been entered.

Where is the user supposed to input these kinds of things? Is this done from the python shell, or from the command line, do I need to turn it into an executable?

Can someone help clarify where the user is inputting all this information?

I'll put in a segment of code, although I don't think it's necessary to answer my questions, but maybe it'll give you a better idea of my issue.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print 'need filename'
    sys.exit(-1)

table = SymbolTable()
parser = Parser(sys.argv[1])
parser.advance()
line = 0

while parser.hasMoreCommands():
    if parser.commandType() == 'L_COMMAND':
        table.addEntry(parser.symbol(), line)
    else:
        line += 1

    parser.advance()

code = Code()
parser = Parser(sys.argv[1])
parser.advance()

var_stack = 16

while parser.hasMoreCommands():
    cmd_type = parser.commandType()

    if cmd_type == 'A_COMMAND':
        number = 32768

        try:
            addr = int(parser.symbol())
        except:
            if table.contains(parser.symbol()):
                addr = table.getAddress(parser.symbol())
            else:
                table.addEntry(parser.symbol(), var_stack)
                addr = var_stack
                var_stack += 1

        bin_number =  bin(number | addr)[3:]
        assembly = '0' + bin_number
        print assembly
    elif cmd_type == 'C_COMMAND':
        assembly = '111'
        assembly += code.comp(parser.comp())
        assembly += code.dest(parser.dest())
        assembly += code.jump(parser.jump())
        print assembly

    parser.advance()
```

The part to note is at the beginning lines 4-6 where it's checking the file name. So once I run my program I get 'need filename' printed to the screen and an error message that looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Assembler.py", line 98, in <module>
  sys.exit(-1)
SystemExit: -1
```

So where can I input the filename to avoid this error?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the traceback.

Comment: @Joel Cornett The error's in the post. It's below the code. Sorry for the format. I'll edit it.

Comment: Ah, got it. FYI, you can cause it to show up as code by 1) pressing the `{}` button after selecting the text in the editor, 2) indenting it by 4 spaces or more, or 3) enclosing the relevant text in backticks.

Answer (score 8):

The way you have it, Python expects the filename as an argument:

```
python file.py your_file.asm
```

If you want to prompt for a filename, use `raw_input()` (or `input()` for Python 3):

```
filename = raw_input('Enter a filename: ') or 'default_file.asm'
```

Comment: Okay, so I definitely want it as an argument. Would I put the    `python file.py your_file.asm` in the command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` contains command line arguments.
So, this script has to be run through command-line, for getting input, as said by blender, use `raw_input` (or `input`) for getting input from the user, if there are not enough command-line arguments.

Something like this:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print "You can also give filename as a command line argument"
    filename = raw_input("Enter Filename: ")
else:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
```

And change the line

```
parser = Parser(sys.argv[1])
```

To

```
parser = Parser(filename)
```